# ActionBar - PullToRefresh Implement Programatically without using Styles

Tags: android, android-actionbar, pull-to-refresh

Currently I am using Styles.xml combined with java code for defining the PullToRefresh customisations. I want to do all the customisations only through java code, rather than defining them in XML. Can I implement all the customisations programatically?

Here is my xml customisation:

```
<!-- PullToRefresh Customizations -->
<style name="Theme.Holo.CustomPtrHeader" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="ptrHeaderStyle">@style/Widget.Custom.PtrHeader</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Custom.PtrHeader" parent="android:Widget">

    <!-- The background of the header view -->
    <item name="ptrHeaderBackground">#FF69B4</item>

    <!-- Color to tint the progress bar -->
    <item name="ptrProgressBarColor">#FF69B4</item>

    <!-- The strings to be displayed at the various states -->
    <item name="ptrPullText">Pull To Refresh</item>
    <item name="ptrRefreshingText">Refreshing News</item>
    <item name="ptrReleaseText">Loading...</item>
</style>
```

Java code:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) view;

    mPullToRefreshLayout = new PullToRefreshLayout(activity);
    ActionBarPullToRefresh
            .from(activity)
            .insertLayoutInto(viewGroup)
            .theseChildrenArePullable(R.id.gridview_news_grid,
                    android.R.id.empty).listener(this)
            .setup(mPullToRefreshLayout);
}


@Override
public void onRefreshStarted(View view) {

    if (Const.DEBUGGING)
        Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "PullToRefresh Started");

    gridview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            getDataFromServer();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            mPullToRefreshLayout.setRefreshComplete();
            if (getView() != null) {
                gridview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

I think i can use Options() for doing this, but not sure how to do it correctly. Can someone help me out regarding this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK.. So I did look into it quite a bit and here is how I solved my problem. We can have full control of the "PullToRefresh" by using `DefaultHeaderTransformer` class. I have removed the "PullToRefresh" customisations from Styles.xml and used the below code to change the colors of progressbar and view background as a whole. You can experiment on it as per your need. If you have any questions, I can answer them.

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) view;

    mPullToRefreshLayout = new PullToRefreshLayout(activity);
    ActionBarPullToRefresh
            .from(activity)
            .options(Options.create().scrollDistance(.75f).build())
            .insertLayoutInto(viewGroup)
            .theseChildrenArePullable(R.id.gridview_features_grid,
                    android.R.id.empty).listener(this)
            .setup(mPullToRefreshLayout);       

    DefaultHeaderTransformer transformer = (DefaultHeaderTransformer) mPullToRefreshLayout
            .getHeaderTransformer();
    transformer.getHeaderView().findViewById(R.id.ptr_text)
            .setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
    transformer.setProgressBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
}
```

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]